Azure Text to speech - voice reading in wrong language(s)
(With python) I have been trying to convert slovenian text to speech with Azure using the multilingual voices, but many of them have the habit of mistaking the text for english and returning a garbled “american accent” from time to time. I also suspect that it may be mistakenly pronouncing some sentences thinking them to be Croatian. I have:
speech_config.speech_synthesis_language = “sl-SI”
so the lack of consistent output is unexpected. I have tried this on a sentence by sentence basis, as well as by paragraph, and for whatever reason some sentences will not be read properly, even if all others in the same call are.
How can I avoid this?

please the code in text as well. sl-SI is for Slovenian (Slovenia) we have sl-SI-PetraNeural (Female) and sl-SI-RokNeural (Male)

use    speech_config.speech_synthesis_voice_name = 'sl-SI-PetraNeural'(or)sl-SI-RokNeural(or) speech_config.speech_synthesis_voice_name = 'sl-SI-PetraNeural'

I don’t have this issue using the petra or rok voices, but as mentioned above this issue arises with the multilingual voices which do support slovenian.

We have to  use  Speech Synthesis Markup Language (SSML) to control language or accent.<lang xml:lang="string"></lang>

please try like this```speech_config.speech_synthesis_voice_name = "sl-SI-PetraNeural"
audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioOutputConfig(use_default_speaker=True)
speech_synthesizer = speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
ssml_text = """


Pozdravljeni, kako ste danes? Veseli me, da lahko uporabljate Azure Text to Speech.


""" ```

When using Text-to-Speech, the input text will mistaking taken as English, shown in the sample image below:

We have to  use  Speech Synthesis Markup Language (SSML) to control language or accent.
Multilingual voices  in Azure Text-to-Speech can automatically detect the language of the input text. However, using the <lang xml:lang="string"></lang> SSML tag allows you to specify a particular language like below:
ssml_text = """

<speak xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" version="1.0" xml:lang="sl-SI">

<voice name="sl-SI-PetraNeural">

Pozdravljeni, kako ste danes? Veseli me, da lahko uporabljate Azure Text to Speech.

</voice>

</speak>

"""

Below example is text-to-speech for Slovenian using SSML.
ssml_text = """

<speak xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" version="1.0" xml:lang="sl-SI">

<voice name="sl-SI-PetraNeural">

Pozdravljeni, kako ste danes? Veseli me, da lahko uporabljate Azure Text to Speech.

</voice>

</speak>

"""

The language code sl-SI  for Slovenian (Slovenia). Azure offers two voices for this language:
sl-SI-PetraNeural (Female) and sl-SI-RokNeural (Male)
Refer to this doc for  Language support  in Speech service
Below is an example Python script for Slovenian text-to-speech synthesis:
import os
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk


speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(
    subscription=os.environ.get("SPEECH_KEY"),
    region=os.environ.get("SPEECH_REGION")
)
speech_config.speech_synthesis_voice_name = "sl-SI-PetraNeural"  
audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioOutputConfig(use_default_speaker=True)
speech_synthesizer = speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)


ssml_text = """
<speak xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" version="1.0" xml:lang="sl-SI">
    <voice name="sl-SI-PetraNeural">
        Pozdravljeni, kako ste danes? Veseli me, da lahko uporabljate Azure Text to Speech.
    </voice>
</speak>
"""

speech_synthesis_result = speech_synthesizer.speak_ssml_async(ssml_text).get()

if speech_synthesis_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted:
    print("Speech synthesized successfully.")
elif speech_synthesis_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
    cancellation_details = speech_synthesis_result.cancellation_details
    print(f"Speech synthesis canceled: {cancellation_details.reason}")
    if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
        print(f"Error details: {cancellation_details.error_details}")



How does using the SSML tags to set up “sl-SI” differ from programaticaly setting speech_synthesis_language to “sl-SI”? Also, this response is still using the petra (or rok) slovenian voices which are not what I'm having trouble with. My issue is with the multilingual voices, (e.g. en-US-OnyxTurboMultilingualNeural) failing to interpret text as slovenian even with the synthesis language set as such.

@Deck Using SSML  tags  allows specifying the language of specific text segments, giving you fine-grained control over how each part . On the other hand, setting the language programmatically with speech_synthesis_language (e.g., speech_config.speech_synthesis_language = "sl-SI") applies the language setting to the entire speech synthesis session, which can lead to inconsistencies, especially when using multilingual voices.
